# Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: magento2, error

I am getting this warning when im trying to add a product:

```
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in 

/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper/Plugin/Configurable.php on line 145
```

**this is the code:**

```
    }
  $extensionAttributes>setConfigurableProductLinks(array_filter($associatedProductIds));
    }
```

I dont understand why.
[image]

Comment: Use [gettype($associatedProductIds)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) to see if it is indeed a string, and use a [vardump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see it's actual content.  From there, update your question, because we are going to need a little more information/effort on your part in order to help

Comment: @amit bera can you please show me how the code should look like so i can copy paste it. im a very beginner at programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Found Solution after R&D On Magento database.
Login In your phpmyadmin
Go to your website database
Open "eav_attribute" table
Find Your multiselect "attribute_id"
Edit Row
If "backend_model" Column blank then paste this
`Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend`

[image]

Comment: Yes I have value in that column as above screenshot, still my value not getting saved.

Comment: magento version?

Comment: working on 2.3.0 @Jugal

Comment: solution only for Magento version 2.2.X!
Not Idea for solution in  2.3.0! i will check in 2.3 for this

Comment: Yes please, @Jugal, That will be a great help!! here is my ticket https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260079/multiselect-attribute-not-saving-in-magento-2

Comment: Thanks for sharing.. my issue solved on magento 2.2.6

Comment: ok thanks very much

Comment: please contact me@ Ask Bytes

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when attempting to save a configurable product, and it was due to the sheer amount of individual configurations assigned to the parent product (over 1,600!). Whenever you save a configurable product, it also processes each of these simple products, leading to one large Ajax request (at least 1MB). When I analysed the network information within the browser's Developer Tools, this Ajax call was throwing a 413 "Request Entity Too Large" error.

The solution for me was to adjust the settings on your server to handle larger requests. If you're running Apache, you can add `LimitRequestBody 8388608` to the .htaccess file (I think); if you're running Nginx, add `client_max_body_size 8M;` within the http, server, or location context within the nginx.conf, and then restart the service. These will both increase the maximum size to 8MB.