# Multiselect attribute not saving in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, customer-address, address-attribute, backend-model

I have created the multi-select attribute for customer address using below code.

```
Setup/UpgradeData.php

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'address_purpose', [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Address Purpose',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AddressPurpose'
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'address_purpose')
            ->setData([
                'used_in_forms' =>  ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address','customer_address']
            ]);
        $attribute->save();
```

Here is my AddressPurpose.php

```
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

 class AddressPurpose extends AbstractSource
  {
   public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
           'option1' => [
            'label' => 'Delivery',
            'value' => 'delivery'
        ],
        'option2' => [
            'label' => 'General',
            'value' => 'general'
           ]
        ];
     }
   }
```

Using above code customer address attribute created successfully.

When I open any customer in admin and selected the option and click Save, The customer getting saved but the selected options are not getting saved.

Again I edit the same customer, Address purpose attribute values empty with none selected.

Have anyone face this issue? Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: follow this link i think work for you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224621/warning-array-filter-expects-parameter-1-to-be-array/230444#230444

Comment: @RakeshDonga, I have value in that column as like that,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When creating the customer attribute, please take care about following things:
>
> Attribute is added to the attribute set, group

```
customer_eav_attribute
eav_entity_attribute
```

> Attribute is assigned to customer forms

```
customer_form_attribute
```

> And the last one the most important as somehow, people just skip over it and wondering why the customer attribute does not want to save from the backend: **Please make sure to set "is_system" flag in "customer_eav_attribute" table to 0, otherwise the attribute will not be saved.**
>
> It can be done by setting the attribute option to "system" => 0 in attribute parameters inside the install/upgrade script.

Don't forget to flush your cache after all!

[direct link to solution](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1393#issuecomment-338879075)

**Edit**
You can create modules from [here](https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2-module-creator.php) or [here](https://mage2gen.com/)

Comment: hi @Ketan, yes I am setting 'system' => 0, in Upgrade script, please check I have posted full code over there, is any mistake

Comment: have you checked all tbles i asked for check?

Comment: yes Is_system flag is 0 in the table, I have checked it

Comment: can you find your attribute in `customer_eav_attribute`,`eav_entity_attribute` and `customer_form_attribute` table?

Comment: yes, @Ketan, It is there on all other tables except this one table, eav_entity_attribute

Comment: i have update my answer

Comment: Can you pls update to my question, where I am wrong? why it is not storing to another table, where I am doing a mistake? Have you tried my code in your end

Comment: please create attribute by link i gave you,test it as i written in answer if it available in all table it will work

Comment: @Kethan, I am already created module and working there, just for updating address, i can't go with new module, can the solution updated to my question, where i am doing wrong?

Comment: hi @Ketan, I am able to save from admin now, how to set value programmatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89118/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-ketan-borada).

Comment: @KetanBorada can you please check this link i am facing same problem here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267386/custom-customer-attribute-value-not-storing-in-database-magento-2/267392#267392 please

Comment: I found the Clarion Customer Attribute module doesn't save to table `eav_entity_attribute`.  I had to add a before and after observer to support this.  Thanks for this answer though - set me in the right direction as to what the issue was and how to solve.