# custom customer attribute value not storing in database magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, customer-attribute

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var SalesSetupFactory
     */
    private $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    private $quoteSetupFactory;

    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public $customer_attribute_used_in_forms = ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address','customer_account_create','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'];


    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {


        $installer = $setup;
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


       if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.3.6') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();


            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'pincode', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'PINCODE',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            'pincode');

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'pincode')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create']
            ]);

              $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Mobile',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            'mobile');

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create']
            ]);


            $attribute->save();
       }




    }
}
```

> Here pincode attribute not storing in db,can you please guide me.after editing from individual customer its not loading the data.

Comment: hi guys please update the same version for module.xml with UpgradeData.php then its fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure about how your code works but I have modified it the way you want it to work.
Please try below code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory 
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var SalesSetupFactory
     */
    private $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    private $quoteSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory 
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var array 
     */
    public $customer_attribute_used_in_forms = ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address','customer_account_create','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory 
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;


    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
     * @param QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {


        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.3.6') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();


            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'pincode', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'PINCODE',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
                null,
                'pincode');

            $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'pincode')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create']
                ])->save();;

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Mobile',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
                null,
                'mobile');

            $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create']
                ])->save();

        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

And let me know if ever you'll get an error.

Comment: my code is working fine and updated the same version for module.xml with UpgradeData.php then its fine